# Intent Chooser for send Message not SMS

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Send message throgh variouse Apps like WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter etc.

now I am using this:

```
Intent messageIntent = 
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.fromParts("smsto",showPhone.getText().toString(),null));
```

What should I use instead of smsto?

It will ask only for SMS Apps I want All message apps like Whatsapp, Facebook etc.

Answer (score 2):

try this,it ll help you in this

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(textToShare));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,titleOfSharingWindow));
```

Comment: I want pass a number also to Message, WhatsApp apps. It seems it in not possible on above code

Comment: I want to pass number to Send sms..and i tried you code bt it is not showing Message app (android default)

Comment: It works for me partially, so I am not accepting your answer but giving you +1 vote up

Comment: What if you know the number / contact?